# Schema and Rich Snippets for embedded YouTube videos in an onclick iframe player?

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, video, iframe, youtube

My site has YouTube thumbnails that when clicked, load a 90% full screen overlay on the page with the youtube video in an `iframe`. JavaScript creates the `iframe` and the video is played.

So the videos are not technically embedded on the page until a user has clicked on the video title or thumbnail. The title and thumbnails are technically `<a href="video"` links with an `onclick` event that loads them into the overlay `iframe` player.

Would it be wise for me to add schema and rich snippets to the page for each of the videos that are listed? Each page has roughly 40-50 videos. Can I add schema and snippets for all of these?

I would like to get the videos indexed in Google video search results and want to make sure that this is an acceptable way of using schema/snippets and that I'm in no risk of getting penalized by the bot for using schema when the videos aren't in iframes until clicked.

### Here is the schema code I'm looking to use:

Schema:

```html
<div itemprop="video" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
  <h2>Video: <span itemprop="name">Title</span></h2>
  <meta itemprop="duration" content="T1M33S" />
  <meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="thumbnail.jpg" />
  <meta itemprop="contentURL" content="http://www.example.com/video123.flv" />
  <meta itemprop="embedURL" content="http://www.example.com/videoplayer.swf?video=123" />
  <meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2011-07-05T08:00:00+08:00" />
  <meta itemprop="expires" content="2012-01-30T19:00:00+08:00" />
  <meta itemprop="height" content="400" />
  <meta itemprop="width" content="400" />
  <object ...>
    <param ...>
    <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" ...>
  </object>
  <span itemprop="description">Video description</span>
</div>
```

Rich Snippet:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "VideoObject",
  "name": "Title",
  "description": "Video description",
  "thumbnailUrl": "https://www.example.com/thumbnail.jpg",
  "uploadDate": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
  "duration": "PT1M33S",
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Example Publisher",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://example.com/logo.jpg",
      "width": 600,
      "height": 60
    }
  },
  "contentUrl": "https://www.example.com/video123.flv",
  "embedUrl": "https://www.example.com/videoplayer.swf?video=123",
  "interactionCount": "2347"
}
</script>
```

Comment: For reference, here is Google's documentation about video schema markup and how it uses that data for video search: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/video

Comment: I’m confused. Why did you label the JSON-LD example with "Rich Snippet" and the Microdata example with "Schema"? -- In case there is a misunderstanding: rich snippets are special search results in search engines like Google Search. You can’t "add" a rich snippet, you can just provide Schema.org markup that is necessary for a specific rich snippet and hope that the search engine enables the rich snippet for your page in their results.

Comment: Maybe try to add the review schema markup, this will probably force google to think that the video is related to a product which you are reviewing

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing, what would be saing against structured data for your videos. You page with videos looks like a kind of curated catalog, so you have all arguments to markup it with structured data.

With indexation it could be a bit complexer, because Google already knows all these videos - they are probably hosted at YouTube, correct?

If you really want to get them indexed on your page... I would invest some more afforts in it and create some unique content for each video - like custom descriptions.

Yes, i know - such file amount as you mentioned is not a childrens game, but, i mean, you should give Google a cause to mean this page is unique and useful. Some unique descriptions, some external backlinks - and you are done.

Maybe its a good idea too - to implement some comments (reviews) on the video page.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas @Evgeniy - I do have a way to make good, custom descriptions that I was thinking of implementing with this. You have some good insight to think about